# Data validation in n-tier application, does one require to apply validations on each tier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, wcf, n-tier-architecture

I have the application compliance check requirement mentioned below regarding the service tier applications (WCF services + Web API based).

**Req:**

*"Each element and attribute value communicated in a web service request MUST be described with the expected data type, the expected length and/or range, and whenever appropriate a formal specification describing the acceptable data
Motivation: The detailed WSDL specification (including regular expressions) allows a much better description of the element and/or attribute values that are expected in an input parameter of the web service request.
Implementation example: An example for such a formal specification are regular expressions, e.g. “([A-Za-z0-9]+[._+&#%/=~])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@([-A-Za-z0-9]+[.])+[A-Zaz]{ 2,6}” to specify a valid e-mail address. The base type "int" SHOULD be replaced by an application-specific subtype that exactly defines the needed integer range. Equivalently the base type "string" MUST be replaced by an application-specific subtype that limits the string's length through "maxLength" and "minLength"."*

My services are not fulfilling the above because In my application, I have web-tier (ASP.NET MVC) on the top and data validation and model validations are already there on web-tier. So to avoid duplication we simply ignored the same on service tier. Additionally, most of the services are not exposed to the outer world except a few.

So, here what is the general practice while designing the n-tier applications does one need to apply data validation on each tier (i.e. front end web tier, service tier, ORM, database). Though mostly I noticed we apply data constraints on databases and on the front end web tier?

Comment: I think you can try to implement it first, and then post the problem when you encounter specific errors in the process.

Comment: @TheobaldDu, I have already implemented the same and there is no such programming/coding issue. The concern is due to the code duplication perspective it's recommended to do so or not. We have to consider the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) concept. Another point, what is the standard guideline from an n-tier application development perspective?